# Connecting Microsoft bot framework to Ms Teams (Proactive messages not being displayed in Ms Teams)

Tags: c#, frameworks, bots

I'm not being able to display proactive messages in Microsoft Teams from my microsoft BOT V4.
The bot is currently deployed in Azure and it's able to connect to the Microsoft team channel.
Other messages are being displayed.  However, the proactive messages are not being displayed.  It is working well in web chat.

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.


using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EchoBotnivin.services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using ATR_AQ_2;
using EchoBotnivin.domain;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EchoBotnivin.Controllers
{
   [Route("api/notify")]
   [ApiController]
   public class NotifyController : ControllerBase
   {
       public static bool notifWhenStateChanges = false;
       public static bool notifWhenAboutToKo = false;
       public static bool notifNewTickets = true;
       public static bool leaaccessrequest = false;
       public static bool notifyCommentsForm = false;
       string tokenAuth;
       int j = 0;
       //private string ServiceUrl;
       private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
       private readonly string _appId;
       private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;

       public NotifyController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IConfiguration configuration, ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences)
       {
           _adapter = adapter;
           _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
           _appId = configuration["MicrosoftAppId"];


           // If the channel is the Emulator, and authentication is not in use,
           // the AppId will be null.  We generate a random AppId for this case only.
           // This is not required for production, since the AppId will have a value.
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_appId))
           {
               _appId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //if no AppId, use a random Guid
           }
       }

       public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
       {
           foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values)
           {
               if (notifNewTickets == true)
                   await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));

           }
           // Let the caller know proactive messages have been sent
           return new ContentResult()
           {
               Content = "<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>",
               ContentType = "text/html",
               StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
           };

       }


       private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
           /* ServiceUrl = "https://teams.microsoft.com";
            var teamConversationData = turnContext.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>();
            var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl), _credentialProvider.AppId, _credentialProvider.Password);
            var userId = "adgsgjjygghghdfgsdfsf";
            var tenantId = "wrewrerweercxgdfdggjdgssd";
            var parameters = new ConversationParameters
            {
                Members = new[] { new ChannelAccount(userId) },
                ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
                {
                    Tenant = new TenantInfo(tenantId),
                },
            };

            var conversationResource = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(parameters);
            var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            message.Text = "This is a proactive message.";
            await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(conversationResource.Id, (Activity)message);
           */
           var token = new Connector();
           tokenAuth = token.getToken();

           var token23 = new Connector();
           dynamic st12 = new servicenowdata();
           st12 = token23.getJobs(tokenAuth);

          Int32 length = st12.Count;
           if (length > 0)
           {
               await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hello!" + Environment.NewLine + $"Trust you are well" + Environment.NewLine + $"Hope that you are having a good day" + Environment.NewLine + $"We are contacting you concerning lea access requests" + Environment.NewLine + $"Could you please review the following tasks if any and add the required information!"), cancellationToken);
               //await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Please type ok to continue!"), cancellationToken);
               await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Could you please click on the below button to continue?"));

               var card = new HeroCard
               {
                   //Text = "Could you please click on the below button to continue?",
                   Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                       {
                           new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "lea access request", value: "lea access request"),
                       },
               };
               var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
               await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);

               //The above tickets have just been assigned to our group could you please check. Have a nice day ahead
           }



        }


   }

}
```

Comment: Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Hello Team, have someone worked on this before